# Id null in Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I develop with java. In the service layer I got the values from db such as "diagnosisTitle", "givenDate" etc. also in the Report entity I mapped OneToMany to Laboratorian and Patient. When findById function calls Report values it works perfectly. But at the Controller side Laboratorian id and Patient id comes null.

here is my Service :

```
public ReportResponse findReportById(Long id) {
        Optional<Report> report = reportRepository.findById(id);
        if(report.isPresent()){
            return modelMapper.map(report.get(), ReportResponse.class);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

here is my Controller :

```
@GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ReportResponse> findReportById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){

        ReportResponse resultReport = reportService.findReportById(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(resultReport);
    }
```

here is the postman output when I send a GET localhost:8080/report/findById/102:

```
{
    "fileNo": 102,
    "diagnosisTitle": "Kriz",
    "diagnosis": "Açıklama",
    "givenDate": "2023-02-27T08:07:41.382+00:00",
    "imageName": null,
    "labIdNo": null,
    "patientId": null
}
```

I think I made a mistake about the Model Mapping.

Comment: So if you already suspect that your mapping might be incorrect, wouldn't it make sense to show us your mapping?

Answer (score -1):

Okay I solved by mapping the Laboratorian and Patient entities to their IDs using the map() method of the ModelMapper object.

```
public ReportResponse findReportById(Long id) {
Optional<Report> report = reportRepository.findById(id);
if(report.isPresent()){
    ReportResponse reportResponse = modelMapper.map(report.get(), ReportResponse.class);
    reportResponse.setLaboratorianId(report.get().getLaboratorian().getId());
    reportResponse.setPatientId(report.get().getPatient().getId());
    return reportResponse;
}
return null;}
```

Comment: always double vet mappings, tamam mı küpeli?